# Assignment is treated as initialization

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I've written the following and expected `a` to be initilized with `4` rvalue. But it didn't:

```
struct A
{
    const int a;

    A() //ctor-initializer is not specified, therefore no initialization for a is performed
    {
        a = 4; //initialization
    }
};

A a;
```

What's wrong? Why does compiler complain?

Comment: Assignment is assignment, even when done in a constructor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So I'm not clear about the initialization concept. I though it was specifing a value for an entity for the first time.

Comment: Initialization is only done at time of definition, either as a direct initialization (e.g. `const int a = 4;`) or through the constructors *initialization* list. The comment is spot-on, "no initialization for a is performed".